# Yii 2.0 migration ReflectionException message 'Class yii\gii\Module does not exist' from git project

Tags: git, yii, yii2

I am trying to execute a migration script, however I keep getting this Exception:

```
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class yii\gii\Module does not exist'
```

in /home/user/project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:408.

The exception also occurs using any other Yii functionality, for instance:

```
./Yii migrate/create test
```

I currently have the latest version of Yii. I've been at this for some time now, but have no idea how to proceed from here.

I cloned this project from git..

Answer (score 1):

I loaded this project via GIT. Alot of the Vendor files are ignored by GIT (via .gitignore).

I ran the follwing command:

```
composer install
```

This solved the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you're **not using "--no-dev" switch in your development environment** during composer installation:

```
composer install --no-dev
```

This way, all packages listed in ("**require-dev**") in your composer JSON file (like *Debug*, *Gii*, *Codeception* etc.) will be ignored.